# Looping over related (M2M) items in the order specified by the intermediatry relationship

Tags: django, templates, sorting, many-to-many

Using the example from the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

I can loop over the groups and show the people in each:

```
{% for group in group_list %}
 {{ group.name }}:
 {% for member in group.members.all %}
  {{ member.name }}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I can't figure out how to show the members **in the order they joined** (i.e., by membership.date_joined). Using dictsort after the all like so:

```
{% for member in group.members.all|dictsort:"date_joined" %}
```

results in an empty member list. And I've tried using members.through, but can't seem to get any data from that, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work around:

In the model for class Group, I added a method

```
def members_by_date(self):
 return Membership.objects.filter(group = self).order_by('date_joined')
```

And in the template:

```
{% for membership in group.members_by_date %}
 {{ membership.person.name }}
```

I would still like to know how to do on-the-fly ordering in the template, though, using dictsort or otherwise, if anyone has a hint for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [`ordering` attribute in the model's `Meta`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) -- then all queries on that model will be ordered that way by default.

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_joined']
```

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that I did exactly that, and that the results of the template above still come out in arbitrary order.

Comment: (Or, rather, they seem to come out in the "ordering" specified by the Meta on People (that is, alpha by name).)